# SSL/TLS Handshake Error "bad certificate" when using stream_socket_client in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, websocket

I am encountering an SSL/TLS handshake error with the message "bad certificate" while attempting to establish a secure connection using stream_socket_client in PHP. The goal is to integrate our PHP application with an external service that requires SSL/TLS encryption.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
private function createSocketConnection($host, $port)
    {
        // Path to the client certificate and private key
        // $localCertificateFile = '/var/www/sslcert/suezpublic.crt';
        // $privateKeyFile = '/var/www/sslcert/privatekesy.pem';

        // Create a secure SSL/TLS context with client certificates
        $contextOptions = [
            'ssl' => [
                'local_cert' => '/var/www/sslcert/suezcombined.pem',
                // 'local_pk' => '/var/www/sslcert/privatekesy.pem',
                'cafile' => '/var/www/sslcert/bizswitch.pem', // GoDaddy Intermediate certificate or your CA certificate
                'verify_peer' => true, // Enable peer certificate verification
                'verify_peer_name' => true, // Check that the common name exists and matches the host name
                'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT, // Use TLSv1.2
                // 'crypto_timeout' => 30, // Increase the handshake timeout to 30 seconds
                'CN_match' => 'www.suezelectric.com', // Ensure the common name matches the server's hostname
                'ciphers' => 'HIGH:!SSLv2:!SSLv3', // Specify allowed ciphers for security
                'disable_compression' => true, // Disable SSL/TLS compression for security
                'capture_peer_cert' => true,
                'capture_peer_chain' => true,
                // 'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'debug' => true, // Enable SSL debugging
            ],
        ];
        $context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket connection
        $socket = stream_socket_client("tls://$host:$port", $errno, $errstr, 30);

        if ($socket === false) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create socket: [$errno] $errstr");
        }

        // Enable SSL/TLS on the stream
        $secured = stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT);

        if ($secured === false) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to enable SSL/TLS on the socket");
        }

        return $socket;

        // Now you can use the $socket to send/receive data with the server using SSL/TLS
        // For example, you can use fwrite($socket, $data) to send data to the server.
    }
```

I have verified the following:

- The client certificate (public_cert.crt) and private key (private_key.pem) are valid and correctly matched.
- The CA certificate (server_cert.pem) is provided and contains the necessary intermediate certificates.
- The STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT and 'ciphers' settings are compatible with the server's configuration.

Interestingly, when the server admintrators disable authentication on the server-side, the SSL/TLS handshake completes successfully. However, when authentication is enabled, the "bad certificate" error occurs, and it has also been noticed that the server is receiving an empty certificate chain.

I have already tried debugging with error_log and verified that the certificate files' paths are correct.

Is there anything I am missing in my SSL/TLS configuration or any potential pitfalls when using stream_socket_client in PHP that could be causing this error?

Any guidance or insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `'verify_peer' => false,` ??? Bad idea. Anyway you should be using `tls://` stream, not `tcp://` or it won't apply the correct context options.

Comment: Uh, also you are creating the `$context` object after it's being used...

Comment: Thank you @miken32 I have updated the code with my recent implementation and it is still the same error

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *"the server is receiving an empty certificate chain"*? From what information you are deriving this information? Also, what exactly is `suezcombined.pem` and how does it relate to `public_cert.crt` and `private_key.pem` you mention in your description but which are not used in the code.

Comment: I had a call with the providers earlier today and they mentioned that the reason why I get the bad certificate error is that at their end they see an empty certificate

Comment: Your code is still full of basic errors. You are not using the `$context` variable at all, and you are using a bunch of context options that [don't exist](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php) to create it. If you use `tls://` stream, you don't need to use `stream_socket_enable_crypto()`.

Comment: @miken32 please can you help debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @miken32 for pointing me to the resource https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php I have been able to resolve my issue. Hence, I thought I should post it as an answer

```
private function createSocketConnection($host, $port)
{
    // Create a secure SSL/TLS context with client certificates
    $contextOptions = [
        'ssl' => [
            'local_cert' => '/filepath/public_cert.pem',
            'cafile' => '/filepath/server_cert.pem',
            'verify_peer' => true,
            'verify_peer_name' => true,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
        ],
    ];
    $context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket connection
    $socket = stream_socket_client("tcp://$host:$port", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);

    if ($socket === false) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to create socket: [$errno] $errstr");
    }

    return $socket;
}
```

With this, I have successfully established an SSL connection to the server. It is also good to note that when using `stream_socket_client()` to connect to the socket, old methods like `socket_write`, `socket_read`, and `socket_close` will no longer work. I changed them to `fwrite`, `fread` and `fclose` respectively